# wsdl.exe - The element attribute is required for headers when Use=Literal

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I'm using MS wsdl.exe to generate C# file from a WSDL file, but get a error describes that "the element attribute is required for headers when Use=Literal"

How can I get rid of this?  Is there any other tools to generate C# from wsdl?

```
    <message name="SomeHeader">
        <part name="Version" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
```

....

```
    <operation name="xxxxx">
        <soap:operation soapAction="xxxx"/>
        <input>
            <soap:header use="literal" message="SomeHeader" part="Version" />
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </output>
    </operation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by replace "type" with "element".

Modified above wsdl to

```
<wsdl:types> 
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"
                elementFormDefault="qualified">

        <xsd:element name="Version" type="xsd:string"/>
        ....
        ....
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>


<message name="SomeHeader">
    <part name="Version" element="tns:Version"/>
</message>
```